# How to rearrange a CSV?

Tags: python, excel

How to rearrange a CSV?

I'm trying to rearrange this data set into years so that:

```
country1 | price | year1
country2 | price | year1
country1 | price | year2
country2 | price | year2
```

becomes:

```
         | year1 | year2 
country1 | price | price
country2 | price | price
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheEconomist/big-mac-data/master/source-data/big-mac-source-data.csv

How can I do that?

Comment: python pandas package allows you to manipulate data: read csv, manipulate it and save it as a csv. You may want to read about `groupby` command for you needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (I used the data from your link and assumed which columns you need):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                 usecols=['name', 'local_price', 'date'],
                 index_col='name')
df.sort_values(by=['name', 'date'], inplace=True)
df = df.pivot(columns='date', values='local_price')
df.to_csv('data_out.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.pivot()`:

```
df.pivot(index='Country', columns='Year', values='Price')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pandas pivot_table:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Year', values='Price')
```

Output:

```
  year    year1  year2
country
country1  price  price
country2  price  price
```